# Swift Array index assigned to variable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to find the array index of the selected element in a table and assign it to a variable.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let kategorilerVC = KategoriController()
    let kategoriIndexCode = firstList[indexPath.row]
    print(kategoriIndexCode)
    //self.present(kategorilerVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm trying to send the index of the selected element to another page.

Comment: The array index of the selected element is `indexPath.row`. That's what the `indexPath` parameter is there for.

Comment: Unrelated but in a storyboard environment `KategoriController()` is not the instance you expect.

Comment: Are you simply asking for `let kategoriIndexCode = "\(indexPath.row)"` ?

Comment: @HangarRash i want to see the index number of the array in the output. Not the name. such as example 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Did you look at the code I just put in my last comment? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array index is `indexPath.row`, which is the same variable you are using to access the value of the array when you do this:

```
firstList[indexPath.row]
```

So in your code, you could do this:

```
let kategoriIndexCode = indexPath.row
```

Comment: when I use this, the name of the item appears in the output, I want the index number.

Comment: `indexPath.row` IS the index number.

Comment: @Fogmeister i added a picture

Comment: @selim I saw... but your picture is just a picture of the code that was already there and doesn't add anything.

Comment: @Fogmeister i want to see the index number of the array in the output. Not the name. such as example 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: That _is_ what `indexPath.row ` gives you: 0,1,2,3,4,5…

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully show you what I mean.

Comment: @selim right… so why do you not understand that indexPath.row is the value you are looking for? I’ve said that a few times.